# How to use Functions in FreeRTOS Tasks

Tags: c, freertos

I was wondering how i can use functions that im going to implement myself in FreeRTOS.
Example: if i want to create any function like `calculateTotal` of two values (just an example), how can i use it with the Task? should i prevent using functions outside `Tasks`and instead write plain code of all functions in the `Task` ? can anybody help me out ?

```
void randomTask(void* param) {
    //initialize something

    for(;;){

    //can i call functions here and define them outside?
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Just call them the same way you'd usually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define functions outside and call them from the tasks. These functions are executed in the context of the calling task, and they use the stack memory allocated for the task.

You can also call the same function from different tasks, as long as they are stateless. A function is stateless if it doesn't use global variables and static local variables. Of course, you can provide a state (context) as a function parameter.

Comment: I can also use Synchronizations objects to allow the access just for one function and then release that to be used for a second function as well right ?

Comment: Yes, it works for functions with states. For example, if your function accesses a global variable, you can use a mutex around that function call. You can also place synchronization mechanisms into the function so it looks prettier on the client side.